# StorageFile Async usage in a NON Metro application

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, isolatedstorage, async-await

I am trying to create an instance of StorageFile in my class library...

```
var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile destinationFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(destination, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
```

VS11 is not building say: 'await' requires that the type 'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation' have a suitable GetAwaiter method. Are you missing a using directive for 'System'?

obviously I am using .net 4.5 as target and I am referencing Windows Assemblies...
not sure why this code work in MetroStyle but does not build in a class library... How can I create an instance of Storagefile in a class library??? at this stage it is not important if the file is created in an async way...

pls let me know your thoughts...
Stelio

Comment: In the Metro style, are there any extra using statements at the top of the code file?

Answer (score 10):

What worked for me is to "manually" add the TargetPlatformVersion

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetPlatformVersion>8.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and in Item group add the following

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime" />
  <Reference Include="System.Runtime" />
  <Reference Include="Windows" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Then the project should compile normaly.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue.The problem was system namespace is missing in the namespace header.I just included system in the namespace and it worked. hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you are trying to use a type from the WinRT libraries because the `StorageFile` [class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR227171) states it applies to Metro only and it is found in `Windows.Storage`.

[This blog post](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jeffreyr/archive/2011/09/20/using-the-windows-runtime-from-a-non-metro-application.aspx) goes through how to build it, but it appears to be a manual process. It also details the cause of the error:

> Using the await keyword causes the compiler to look for a GetAwaiter
>   method on this interface. Since IAsyncOperation does not
>   define a GetAwaiter method, the compiler wants to look for an
>   extension method.

Basically, it looks like you need to add a reference to: `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll`

---

Please take the time to read his blog post, but I will put the important part here for clarity.

---

**Blog Content Below Unceremoniously Plagiarised**

First, in Notepad, I created the following C# source code in EnumDevices.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Foundation;

class App {
    static void Main() {
        EnumDevices().Wait();
    }

    private static async Task EnumDevices() {
        // To call DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync:
        // Reference Windows.Devices.Enumeration.winmd when building
        // Add the "using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;" directive (as shown above)
        foreach (DeviceInformation di in await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync()) {
            Console.WriteLine(di.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Second, I created a Build.bat file which I run from the Developer Command Prompt to build this code (This should be 1 line but I wrap it here for read ability):

```
csc EnumDevices.cs  
/r:c:\Windows\System32\WinMetadata\Windows.Devices.Enumeration.winmd  
/r:c:\Windows\System32\WinMetadata\Windows.Foundation.winmd 
/r:System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll  
/r:System.Threading.Tasks.dll
```

Then, at the command prompt, I just run the EnumDevices.exe to see the output.

Comment: I think it should be pointed out what Jeffrey Richter metiones in his post: the missing assembly is System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll.

Comment: Guys, thanks for the prompt response... I was trying to use the background downloader from a WPF application on Windows 8 (in a NON-Metro context) but I guess it is not a good idea and it is better to use BITS.... but I think that using the interop with the windowsRuntime is not a good idea...

Comment: I get the following error when trying to run the example from the blog: `numDevices.cs(14,35): error CS4028: 'await' requires that the type
       'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceIn
       formationCollection>' have a suitable GetAwaiter method. Are you missing
       a using directive for 'System'?`

Comment: @Hjulle Do you have a using statement at the top of the file? `using System;`. Also, are you running a late enough version of VS on the relevant C# version to get the `await` keyword support?

Comment: Yes, I copied the example exactly. I assume it has `await` keyword support since it is looking for a `GetAwaiter` method and not complaining about unknown keyword or something. But I do not run VS, I'm using the `csc` compiler that comes with the .NET 4.5 runtime.

Answer (score 1):

It must be a long time since the post when I 
After adding references:
System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll
System.Threading.Tasks.dll

and targeting windows 8 in project file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetPlatformVersion>8.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Mentioned above example can be compiled in VS.

Comment: please post a separate question if you want to ask something.